# Time complexity of the algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This is the algorithm: I think its time complexity is O(n^2) because of loop in loop. How can I explain that?

```
FindSum(array, n, t) 
i := 0 
found := 0 
array := quick_sort(array, 0, n - 1) 
 while i < n – 2 
            j = i + 1 
            k = n - 1 
        while k > j 
             sum = array[i] + array[j] + array[k] 
             if sum == t 
                 found += 1 
                  k -= 1 
                  j += 1 
            else if sum > t 
                 k -= 1 
            else 
                 j += 1
```

Comment: that is this language - can you rewrite it in Ruby ?

Comment: You assumed that items are unique. If this is not true than you would miss some matches (in ```if sum == t```)

Comment: O(n^2) means that in the worst case, to conduct some action over array in your state, you will need to reference each element n times.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you've got time complexity of O(infinity) because you never increment `i` or decrement `n` and thus you end up in an endless loop (if you loop at all).

Comment: Thank you for reply. 
This is the whole code: http://pastebin.com/FF0d7M0E

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the complexity is indeed `O(n^2)`.

The inner loops runs anywhere between `k-j = n-1-(i+1) = n-i-2` to `(k-j)/2 = (n-i-2)/2` iterations.

Summing it up for all possible values of `i` from 0 to `n-2` gives you:

```
T = n-0-2 + n-1-2 + n-2-2 + ... + n-(n-2)-2
  = n-2 + n-3 + ... + 0
```

This is sum of arithmetic progression, that sums in `(n-1)(n-2)/2` ([sum of arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum)), which is quadric. Note that dividing by extra 2 (for "best" case of inner loop) does not change time complexity in terms of big O notation.

Comment: My teacher told me that she knows there is n^2, but she want more explanation (for each line).. Is it possible to solve? 
She said "nice, but its not enough" :<

Comment: @matuo Isn't that your task? I gave you a pretty clear explanation, all you need to do is put more details into it, analyze each line, and then analyze the loops as I did. Shouldn't be too hard. Good Luck.

Comment: Well.. I know it, but my teacher wants more and I dont know how to explain more clearly than this what you wrote. Im trying to go line by line, but "its not enough". Maybe she doesnt know what is going on?

Comment: @matuo summarize it line by line, similarly to what I did here for loops, but with more details.